# How can I use a static library in a React Native iOS application?

Tags: objective-c, react-native, interop

I have a static library written in Rust that is compiled against the iOS CPU architecture, but I don't know how to link it when my Native Module for iOS is compiled. So with this code:

```
#import "SolClientModule.h"
#import "solclient.h"

@implementation SolClientModule
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

char* g_text;

void getTextCallback(struct Text text) {
  strcpy(g_text, text.content);
}

RCT_EXPORT_BLOCKING_SYNCHRONOUS_METHOD(getName)
{
  foo(&getTextCallback);

  NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",g_text];
  return message;
}

@end
```

The compiler is not satisfied with the `foo` function because the corresponding .h file and .a file were not linked during the compilation process.

Comment: can you port `rust ` code to `c++` then expose them to React Native through JSI

Comment: In either case rust will be compiled to a library, and I will need to use it. It is more of a "right way to use compiler" kind of problem IMO.